# Ignore/Exclude specific Objective-C exceptions from the global exception breakpoint in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception

Xcode has this neat feature to add an exception breakpoint. If I add one I can choose between "All", "Objective-C" and "C++" exceptions.

However, I'm using a framework (Evernote iOS SDK) that heavily relies on exceptions, throws them and catches them within the framework. This triggers my exception breakpoint even when those exceptions would never hit my code.

Is there a way to ignore some kind/some subclasses of exceptions?

Evernote defines them like this:

```
@interface EDAMUserException : NSException <NSCoding> {}
```

So, I would like to exclude all those from triggering my exception breakpoint.

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109102/xcode-4-exception-breakpoint-filtering), but not yet an answer.

Comment: Did you find a way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, not yet. Will ask at the next WWWDC;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is! Another question about this garnered this answer: [Ignore certain exceptions when using Xcode's All Exceptions breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370632/ignore-certain-exceptions-when-using-xcodes-all-exceptions-breakpoint/19262247#19262247) which includes script and everything. You can ignore exceptions by class or by name. It's awesome.

Comment: Great! Mine was asked about half a year earlier, but they cover the exact same topic ;-)