# Xcode - turn off debug

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints, lldb

Is it possible to turn off debug mode for a specific .m file ?

Summary.
I am writting a framework which will be used in other projects, code contains @try @catch blocks, which handles some exceptions.

Problem.
If framework user turns on Xcode's "All exceptions" breakpoints, then LLDB periodically  stops program (when exception is raised) in @try block.

What I want.
I want to mark my framework files "non sensitive" for lldb (ignore exception breakpoints).

Solutions that I have already tried.
I tryed python script which checks eax/r0 and ignores exception, also a variant with breakpoint condition, but all this solutions are not nice for thousand of newbie third party developers.

Is it possible to have some nice solution?

Thanks.

Comment: possibly a relevant aside: are you using exceptions for flow control within your code, or are they truly "exceptional"? Exceptions aren't intended to be ignored, so if your code can be rewritten to handle certain code paths without exceptions, that would be a much better route.

Comment: Agreed. According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html) `You should not use a try-catch block in place of standard programming checks for Objective-C methods.`

Comment: Clever Error, And what Objective-C method you use for checking existence of segue with identifier ?

Answer (score 0):

[This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370632/ignore-certain-exceptions-when-using-xcodes-all-exceptions-breakpoint) demonstrates how you can create a conditional exception breakpoint for your project. It may be a lot of work to specifically exclude each one of your framework's classes.