# Ignore/exclude autolayout exceptions from the global exception breakpoint in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, exception, autolayout

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370632/ignore-certain-exceptions-when-using-xcodes-all-exceptions-breakpoint/19262247#19262247), I'd like to have the option to ignore Autolayout exceptions, whilst listening for all other global exceptions.

Typically* I get exceptions like:

```
2014-01-30 15:15:01.625 AAU iPhone[18233:70b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
...
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd86e490 V:[UILabel:0xd880c30(21)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd8813a0 V:[UILabel:0xd880c30]-(13)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0xd880990 )>",
```

And I often don't have time to trawl through my storyboard and find the guilty constraint - is there any way of ignoring these exceptions?

My guess so far, is that I could use a symbolic breakpoint, with suitable condition. An example solution for Core Data exceptions is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371689/1202222):

```
(BOOL)(! (BOOL)[[(NSException *)$eax className] hasPrefix:@"_NSCoreData"])
```

Thanks!

*As an unrelated point, Autolayout sucks.

Comment: Auto-layout rocks if you know what you are doing :P

Comment: Ha...well my quest for autolayout enlightenment continues...