# Why I play/preload soundEffect with error in cocos2dx (ios)?

Tags: simpleaudioengine, cocos2d-x-2.x

Whether play or preload sound effect.

code here:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("debug.mp3");
```

I will get this error:
ExtAudioFileOpenURL

[image]

The sound file is exist in app. And file is right.

[image]

Comment: Now I fixed it. just convert the mp3 to a correct format. in ios don't support all format of mp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I fix that.
It cause by I add a "All C++ Exceptions".

[image]

Comment: no, no, my mp3 music format don't support be with ios . it works well after convert with goldwave.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a a valid workaround, but you are not debugging the rest of exceptions. I'm doing this to get rid of this problem:

Add a symbolic exception with this settings:

symbol:

`objc_exception_throw`

condition:

```
(BOOL)(! (BOOL)[[(NSException
*)$eax className] hasPrefix:@"_CDOpen"])
```

Please refer to this answer for more information:

[Ignore certain exceptions when using Xcode's All Exceptions breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370632/ignore-certain-exceptions-when-using-xcodes-all-exceptions-breakpoint)

Comment: no, no, my mp3 music format don't support be with ios . it works well after convert with goldwave.

Comment: Ok thanks, is good to know it. My game was raising the same exception loading a mp3 file, but the mp3 was played without any problem, so I ignored explicity only that exception. I will try goldwave, your solutions seems much better :)