# XCode catch only specific exception

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

How to catch only specific exception in XCode, given the console output

Like to catch only this exception

```
2014-10-06 14:48:58.226 app[80027:303] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-10-06 14:48:58.226 app[80027:303] *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
2014-10-06 14:48:58.226 app[80027:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b8f025c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff90c13e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b7efdd1 -
```

Comment: In Xcode, you can go to the Breakpoints tab, then add a breakpoint for "All Exceptions"

Comment: ok, but i want to catch just this specific one, as sadly i get many exceptions from different subparts

Comment: This might help: [Ignore certain exceptions when using Xcode's All Exceptions breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370632/ignore-certain-exceptions-when-using-xcodes-all-exceptions-breakpoint)

Comment: allright, but i want to catch just this specific one, not to ignore certain exceptions